# YII2 Dependent radiolist on other radiolists

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user, yii2-model

I have two tables, as shown below.

**tbl_tests:**

```
id | testname | description
```

**tbl_testitems:**

```
id | itemname | description | testid
```

I need to user a radiolist for both of them so that when I chose the radiolist for the tests, then only the testitem list within the selected will be shown. Here is my code:

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'labtestid')->radioList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Labratorytest::find()->orderBy('testName')->all(), 'testid', 'testName'), [
    'onchange' => '$.post( "index.php?r=labratorytestitem/lists&id=' . '"+$(this).val(), function(data){
      $( "select#suggesttest-labtestitemid" ).html( data );
    });'
    , 'return' => true], ['id' => 'test'])->label('');
?>
```

and

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'labtestitemid')->radioList($allItemsArray, ['return' => true])->label('')
?>
```

The **actionLists** method inside the **testItemsController** is

```
public function actionLists($id) {
    $countItems = \app\models\Labratorytestitem::find()->where(['testid' => $id])->count();
    $testItems = \app\models\Labratorytestitem::find()->where(['testid' => $id])->all();
    $mymodel = new \app\models\Suggesttest();
    if ($countItems > 0) {
        foreach ($testItems as $item) {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $item->itemName . '" value="' . $item->itemid . '>';
        }
    } else {
        echo ' ';
    }
}
```

But when I select the `radiolist`, it is not showing the items within the test selected. Please help me! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hello Guys Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a few mistakes in your code. Firstly, you're mixing `post` and `get` requests. Your `onchange` event is triggering a `post` request, but you've not specified any data to send. Your controller is then expecting a `get` request, but is not receiving one. You haven't told the yii to end after echoing your data, and the controller name looks wrong, is that a typo?

Anyway, try this code. I've suggested a few code simplifications to make it easier to read.

In your view file;

```
<?=
//Note the url, as you asked for it, is to a controller called `laboratorytestitem`, not `testitems` as you've called the controller
$url = Url::to(['/laboratorytestitem/lists', 'id' => $model->id]);
$js = <<<JS
    $(#suggesttest-labtestid).on('change', function(){
        $.get($url, function(data){
            $( "select#suggesttest-labtestitemid" ).html( data );
        })
    });
JS
$this->registerJs($js);

$form->field($model, 'labtestid')->radioList(
        ArrayHelper::map(Labratorytest::find()->orderBy('testName')->all(), 'testid', 'testName'), ['return' => true, 'id' => 'test'])->label('');
?>
```

Now, in your controller called `laboratorytestitem`, you will have an action `lists`

```
public function actionLists($id) {
    $testItems = \app\models\Labratorytestitem::find()
        ->where(['testid' => $id])
        ->all();
$count = count($testItems);
$output = '';
    if ($count > 0) {
        foreach ($testItems as $item) {
            $output .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $item->itemName . '" value="' . $item->itemid . '>';
        }
    }
    echo $output;
    Yii::$app->end();
}
```

When you run the code, check the output of the console on your browser to make sure it's finding the correct url, and that the data sent is what you expect, and that the response from the server is what you expect. This way you can pin-point any problems.